# C# Form popup location

Tags: c#, forms, popup, location

I am building a popup application to show some notification. I want to show it on the screen at the right-side bottom, in any screen resolution. The screen size is 422 x 217 (width x height). Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*System.Windows.Forms.Timer MyTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); */

        int num = 1;
        this.Hide();
        if (num == 1)
        {
            Form fm = new Form
            {
                Location = new Point(50, 60),
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
                ShowInTaskbar = false
            };
            fm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

I want to make the popup as coming from bottom. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently got code for a 'toaster' popup which comes out from the bottom right corner of any screen. Here is part of the code-behind I used:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() =>
            {
                var workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
                var transform = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;
                var corner = transform.Transform(new Point(workingArea.Right + 15, workingArea.Bottom - 10));

                this.Left = corner.X - this.ActualWidth - 100;
                this.Topmost = true;
                this.Top = corner.Y - this.ActualHeight;

            }));
```

Adjust the `-100`, `+15` and `-10` based on your 'popup' dimensions.